# CSS is not connecting to HTML in IntelliJIDEA Ultimate

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot project on IntelliJ, everything works fine but my html pages are not connecting to the css file. If I open the html in the browser from it folder the style is applied to the html file, but inside the project this is not happening.

**This is one of my html files:**

[image]

**This is my project directory hierarchy**

[image]

**This is my styles.css file:**

[image]

**My WebController class**:

[image]

Does anybody knows what is happening? The CSS plugin is bundled in my project and I have checked the needed plugins but it does not work.

[image]

When I open the html files from my project folder in the files system, the html file works with the CSS style, but from the IntelliJ proyect it DOES NOT

I have put the styles.css file into a new folder "static" outside the "templates" folder, but the problem perssists

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is *styles.css* an HTML template? Why did you put it in the templates folder?

Comment: I have changed it and the problem remains the same...

Comment: Using a relative path to access a static resource seems wrong.

Comment: How could it be then??

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to work out URLs for static resources in spring boot.

Comment: I have read, but i am not sure about what i am doing bad, if you know could you please tell me?

Comment: I don't use spring boot. I know just enough to spot your primary mistake (putting static resources in the templates directory).

Comment: Please do not post text information as images